# Why is this code running before the 'click' event?

Tags: jquery

I have what seems to be a simple issue. I have a jquery function that's running on page load, despite the fact that I specifically set it to run after the 'click' event on a specific element.

This is the function:

```
    $('#boxShow').click(function() {
      $('#colorBox').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 400, function() {
        // Code that will run after the click
      });
    });
```

Is there a way to prevent this code from running before the 'click' event? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The full jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        event: "click"
    });

    $("#TagsSelectBox").multiSelect({ 
        minWidth:130,
        selectedList:5,
        showHeader:false
    });

    $('#boxShow').click(function() {
        $('#colorBox').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
        }, 400, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    $('#test').colorPicker({            
        defaultColor: 0, // index of the default color (optional)
        columns: 13,     // number of columns (optional)  
        click:function(c){
        $('#boxShow').css("background-color",c);
      } 
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**
Just in case anyone wants to know, here's the final version after making a few adjustments to make it generic enough for multiple 'color-pickable' items:

[Final Version](http://pastebin.com/pma0DNCB)

If you want to try it out yourselves, you can download the color picker plugin from the syronex site. The link is in the comments!

Thanks to everyone who helped me achieve this!

Comment: What do you mean before the click event?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Can you show the full code?

Comment: Is something else in your load triggering a `click` event on this element? e.g. `$('#boxshow').click()`?

Comment: There's probably more going on that we need to know about to help you, can you post some more code?

Comment: You must have some other code that **triggers** the **click** for that **animation** to have or either you have the animation ***somewhere outside of the click event***. - Those are the only logical reasons I could see why your animation is happening on pageload

Comment: Still: Which function is running too early?

Comment: The part that has '// Animation complete.'. I'm supposed to persist the color I pick on the database, that's where I'll run this code. But for test purposes, I just put an alert('test'); in there, and it runs on page load, and also when I click it. I only want it to run when I click it.

Comment: this is what happens: When I reload the page on the browser, the code within $('#boxShow').click(function() is running. If I put an alert('test'); in there, it shows up when the page loads. I thought using the click event around a function allowed me to control when it was supposed to run. I only wanted it to run once I clicked the #boxShow element, but it is also running when the page is loaded, even when I don't click #boxShow.

Comment: I just edited the post with the full HTML code necessary to illustrate my point. I hope it helps.

Comment: come on where is your posted `HTML`? I see nothing new

Comment: sorry, I just fixed it. I didn't realize I couldn't post more then one hyperlink, since I'm new here.

Comment: that code doesn't seem to accurate, since your above code uses two methods not shown in the so callded full html code

Comment: It represents the fraction of the code which has the problem. If you download the .js and .css from syronex http://www.syronex.com/software/jquery-color-picker.zip you'll see that the issue is there, despite the fact that I didn't add the rest of the code. You'll see a small square, that displays a box below, full of different colors. This box is being animated on page load, but it's only supposed to be animated when the user clicks the small square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess I'm not sure of what your colorpicker plugin is, so I would say try commenting out the lines that say click on that control, because it might initiate a click to that control

```
$('#test').colorPicker({             
    defaultColor: 0, // index of the default color (optional) 
    columns: 13,     // number of columns (optional)   
    //click:function(c){ 
    //$('#boxShow').css("background-color",c); 
  //}  
});
```

Since it seems as if all your tags are **divs**, try changing the click event function to this

```
$('div').click(function(e) { 
  var $target = $(e.target); 

  if ($target.is('#boxShow')) { 
       $('#colorBox').animate({ 
        height: 'toggle' 
        }, 400, function() { 
        // Code that will run after the click 
      }); 

  } else { 
    // do actions for a click anywhere else inside div
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } 
});
```

If that works then something else is wrong with your code that you have posted.

Comment: Thanks. That was a good idea actually, but it didn't do the trick. $('#colorBox').animate({...}) still runs even though I commented out those 3 lines with the click event from the color picker. I'm going to provide the full HTML code for this, just a minute.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jake. Your code solves my problem! But I'd like to understand why it works, would you kindly explain? I thought the click event alone was supposed block something from happening up until the click.

Comment: @Rafa- As I said there is something else in your code triggering that click event( your problem exist somewhere in your code), so my code make sure that the actual event triggered event is a clicked event and that it **matches** that specific div **id**.

Comment: Also since you're new to the site, dont forget to mark the correct answer to your solution

Comment: hmm, I wonder what it could be.. everything necessary to reproduce the problem I had was on that 'Full Code' link. I hope someone can spot what I did wrong. Any suggestions on how I can debug this? / Ok jake, I'll mark your answer, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: **firebug** can help debug it

Comment: Thanks Jake! I posted the final result at the end of the question. It turned out it actually was the plugin's fault. Somehow it activated the click event without any actual click... But I worked around this issue, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you mean that the query is not getting any elements, and therefore not working.

You need to put it inside a document ready handler to call it after the document loads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#boxShow').click(function() {
      $('#colorBox').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 400, function() {
        // Code that will run after the click
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not what he seems to mean. It seems that the handler is running without his clicking on the element.

Comment: This is the only reason I can think of. I will edit this if there is any info that suggests another problem.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be related to the $(document).ready statement, since it was already there. Just in case I wasn't clear enough, the code that is running is $('#colorBox').animate() and everything within it.